# Is there a way to send multimedia controls (play/pause/next etc) to apps like spotify running on windows from HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched all around google and no luck.

I have also searched for third party multimedia cmd tools but also could not find anything. Please Help!

Comment: The only way is through HTTP requests - and this can only be done if the desktop application runs its own built-in web server. You can use a plugin for WinAmp (https://winampheritage.com/plugin/winamp-web-interface/92511) which implements such a web server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.